# Ldap password policy not throwing different errors

Tags: java, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I use ppolicy overlay and enabled ppolicy_use_lockout to separate between invalid password and locked accounts.

```
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=openiam,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=openiam,dc=com"
rootpw      "{SSHA}2ttRoo/t5HuMT2nPxtI6goVUML5R2H9h"
# PPolicy Configuration
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=policies,dc=openiam,dc=com"
ppolicy_use_lockout
ppolicy_hash_cleartext
```

I tried to lock user account by entering wrong password couple of times (pwdMaxFailure)

The user is being locked but when I try to login again I still get the same error:

Invalid credentials (49)

Any idea why i am not getting diffrent error to disticnt between the cases?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a password policy response control that tells you the error, if you request it with the corresponding request control.

Note that it's a bad idea to let this show through to the user, for the reasons stated in the [password policy draft, section 12](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10). Basically you would be leaking information to an attacker.

Note also that this technique also applies to [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20867842/207421) which I have now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

you should add -e ppolicy when use ldapwhoami to get more information like  (Password expired, 3 grace logins remain)